# subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--config', 'Release', '--', '/m']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, dlib

I was trying to install the dlib package for my face recognition project but error keep getting in the way. This is another error and I don't even know what it means. I am installing it in windows. Please someone help me. I have been working on this issue for about 15 hours still wasn't able to install dlib package for python. Here is the whole log.

I am editing some middle part log due to limit issue.

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (e:\python programmes\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (e:\python programmes\lib\site-packages)
Installing collected packages: dlib
  Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for dlib did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [319 lines of output]
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      running build_ext
      Building extension for Python 3.10.2 (tags/v3.10.2:a58ebcc, Jan 17 2022, 14:12:15) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
      Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\lib.win-amd64-3.10 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=E:\Python programmes\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\lib.win-amd64-3.10 -A x64'
      -- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
      -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19044.
      -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.31.31104.0
      -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.31.31104.0
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working C compiler: F:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.31.31103/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
      -- Detecting C compile features
      -- Detecting C compile features - done
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: F:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.31.31103/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
      -- Detecting CXX compile features
      -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
      -- Found PythonInterp: E:/Python programmes/python.exe (found version "3.10.2")
      -- Found PythonLibs: E:/Python programmes/libs/Python310.lib
      -- pybind11 v2.2.4
      -- Using CMake version: 3.23.0-rc2
      -- Compiling dlib version: 19.23.0
      -- Looking for sys/types.h
      -- Looking for sys/types.h - found
      -- Looking for stdint.h
      -- Looking for stdint.h - found
      -- Looking for stddef.h
      -- Looking for stddef.h - found
      -- Check size of void*
      -- Check size of void* - done
      -- Enabling SSE2 instructions
      -- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
      -- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
      -- Looking for pthread.h
      -- Looking for pthread.h - not found
      -- Found Threads: TRUE
      CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR not found or specified
      -- Could NOT find CUDA (missing: CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) (Required is at least version "7.5")
      -- Found CUDA, but CMake was unable to find the cuBLAS libraries that should be part of every basic CUDA install. Your CUDA install is somehow broken or incomplete. Since cuBLAS is required for dlib to use CUDA we won't use CUDA.
      -- DID NOT FIND CUDA
      -- Disabling CUDA support for dlib.  DLIB WILL NOT USE CUDA
      -- C++11 activated.
      -- Configuring done
      -- Generating done
      -- Build files have been written to: F:/Users/Karan Singh/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-ab7747dh/dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15/build/temp.win-amd64-3.10/Release
      Invoking CMake build: 'cmake --build . --config Release -- /m'
      Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.1.0+ae57d105c for .NET Framework
      Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

        Checking Build System
        Building Custom Rule F:/Users/Karan Singh/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-ab7747dh/dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15/dlib/CMakeLists.txt
       
     
     
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\matrix.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\svm_c_trainer.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\svm_c_trainer.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\svm_rank_trainer.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\svm_rank_trainer.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
        cca.cpp
        sequence_segmenter.cpp
        svm_struct.cpp
        image.cpp
        image2.cpp
        image3.cpp
        image4.cpp
        rectangles.cpp
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\cca.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\cca.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\sequence_segmenter.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\sequence_segmenter.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\image.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\image.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\svm_struct.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\svm_struct.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\image2.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\image2.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\image3.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\image3.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\image4.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\image4.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\rectangles.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\rectangles.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
        object_detection.cpp
        shape_predictor.cpp
        correlation_tracker.cpp
        face_recognition.cpp
        cnn_face_detector.cpp
        global_optimization.cpp
        image_dataset_metadata.cpp
        numpy_returns.cpp
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\object_detection.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\object_detection.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\correlation_tracker.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\correlation_tracker.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
        line.cpp
        gui.cpp
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\face_recognition.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\face_recognition.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\global_optimization.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\global_optimization.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\image_dataset_metadata.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\image_dataset_metadata.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\shape_predictor.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\shape_predictor.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\numpy_returns.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\numpy_returns.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\cnn_face_detector.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\cnn_face_detector.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\gui.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\gui.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,22): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\line.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/numpy.h(35,31): error C2338: ssize_t != Py_intptr_t (compiling source file F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\tools\python\src\line.cpp) [F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\setup.py", line 222, in <module>
          setup(
        File "E:\Python programmes\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "E:\Python programmes\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
          dist.run_commands()
        File "E:\Python programmes\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "E:\Python programmes\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "E:\Python programmes\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
          return orig.install.run(self)
        File "E:\Python programmes\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 568, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "E:\Python programmes\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "E:\Python programmes\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "E:\Python programmes\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "E:\Python programmes\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "E:\Python programmes\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\setup.py", line 134, in run
          self.build_extension(ext)
        File "F:\Users\Karan Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ab7747dh\dlib_86f52d75627b4815b5791527533d7a15\setup.py", line 174, in build_extension
          subprocess.check_call(cmake_build, cwd=build_folder)
        File "E:\Python programmes\lib\subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--config', 'Release', '--', '/m']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> dlib

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (e:\python programmes\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (e:\python programmes\lib\site-packages)
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same error, run the below commands to solve the error :

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
python setup.py install --no DLIB_GIF_SUPPORT
```